# Identifying password encryption in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Long story short I want to be able to read passwords stored in our database to be able to query weak passwords for our employees as there are currently no restrictions. What I've been doing in the past is changing it from the front end to see what it looks like on the backend.  For instance this is what "password" looks like on the back end JXm7CJyoCBnURIrneTtflA== .

I'm not sure if this is possible, or what type of encryption is used.  Any help would be great!!

Thanks

Comment: If it is really a hash, you can't decrypt it back to real password - that's the whole point of hashing.

Comment: I'm not sure it's actually even a hash, I more so want to be able to identify the method of encryption

Answer (score 0):

This particular field is Base64 encoded, and has 16 bytes if you decode it (Convert.FromBase64String). This smells like a MD5 (hash algorithm) - especially if other fields have also 16 bytes when decoded. There is no way in hell how to decrypt hash (there are some options like rainbow tables but you can't be 100% sure). Algorithm works like this: you hash password in db, you hash whatever user puts in as password when he logs in and hash it as well - if hash matches user has entered correct password.